# Fluid image with extra data for cycle2

Tags: typo3, fluid

I'm using cycle2 for a image slider, for adding a title extra data is needed in the image url, so I want to generate the following url:

```
<img src="foto.jpg" data-cycle-title="Title" data-cycle-desc="Subtitle" />
```

I tried the following but this generates an error?

```
<f:image src="foto.jpg" data-cycle-title="Title" data-cycle-desc="Subtitle" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `data-cycle-title` and `data-cicle-desc` are not registered arguments within the `ImageViewHelper` you cant pass those values directly.
But there is a `additionalAttributes` argument for the rescue. You can add as many attributes as you like to have in your image tag. `additionalAttributes` expects an array notation:

```
<f:image ... additionalAttributes="{data-cycle-title: 'Title', data-cycle-desc: 'Subtitle'}" ... />
```